# Convergence of Newton-Raphson given a generic polynomial

Tags: numerical-methods, newton-raphson

Let $f(x) = (x-r_1)(x-r_2)...(x-r_d)$ where $r_1 < r_2 < ... < r_d$. I need to prove that if $x_0 > r_d$, Newton-Raphson converges to $r_d$.

I could see that:

$$f(x) = \prod_{j=1}^d (x-r_j) $$
$$\frac{d}{dx}f(x) = \sum_{i=1}^d 
\prod_{i \neq j}(x-r_j)$$

But I´m stuck.

Comment: Use Rolle's theorem. If all roots are real and different, then all roots of $f'$ are real, different, in between the roots of $f$. Use it once more to say the same of $f''$. Deduce that $f$ is convex and increasing to the right of $r_d$. Convexity gives that $r_d\leq x_{n+1}$ and increasing that $x_{n+1}<x_n$.

Comment: Hint: $g(t) = f(r_d + t)$ is a polynomial with non negative coefficients. (by the way it shows that $r_1\le r_2\le\cdots\le r_d$ suffices).